# How do we read from the Cluster's replicated log?

Tags: aeron

I'm currently trying to replay the inbound messages to the cluster. While the live inbound messages using a simple subscription on the logChannel and logStreamId works, I'm wondering if there's a way to "replay" the channel or read from the log via the startReplay of an Archive Client or any other method.

Comment: Is this related to programming?

Answer (score 2):

The Aeron Cluster log is replicated and feed into clustered services once consensus is reached. When you implement a cluster service it is not necessary to start the replay of the log from the application. If you wish to replay the log for some other reason it is possible but should not be done without a detailed understand of the consensus mechanism.